# Bounds on a recursively defined sequence

Tags: inequality, recursion

I have a sequence defined by $h_0=h_1=1$, $h_2=2$ and $h_{n+1}=(n+1)h_n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. The paper I'm reading claims $n! \le h_n \le 2(n!)$. It is easy to show the first inequality by induction. $$h_{n+1} = (n+1)h_n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \ge (n+1)! + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \ge (n+1)!$$

However, I am having trouble with the other one. Doing the same technique doesn't quite work:
$$h_{n+1}=(n+1)h_n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \le 2(n+1)!+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$ Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the paper trying to analyze a permutation generation algorithm and prove that it is $\theta(n!)$?

Comment: @Aryabhata No, it is on symbolic dynamics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $$\frac{h_n}{n!} = t_n$$

We get

$$t_{n+1} = t_n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2(n+1)!}$$

Thus (adding up the telescopic series $t_{r} - t_{r-1}$) we get

$$t_n = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k(k-1)}{2(k+1)!}$$

Now $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k(k-1)}{2(k+1)!} = \frac{1}{2}(e-2)$ (easily found using taylor series for $e^x$)

And thus $$1 \lt t_n \lt \frac{1}{2}(e-2) \lt 2$$

Comment: @angryavian: $\frac{e^x-1}{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(k+1)!}$. Differentiate twice.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks so much!